# How to use Mailgun with HTTParty in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailgun, rest-client, httparty

I want to use Mailgun with HTTParty in Rails:

```
RestClient.post "https://api:key-###"\
    "@api.mailgun.net/v3/###/messages",
    from: from_email,
    to: to_email,
    subject: title,
    html: body_text
```

It's working but

```
payload = {
    from: email_history.from_email,
    to: email_history.to_email,
    subject: email_history.title,
    html: email_history.body_text,
    multipart: true
}

response = SendEmailJob.post('https://api:key-###'\
'@api.mailgun.net/v3/###/messages', payload)
```

Returns:

```
{
  "message": "'from' parameter is missing"
}
```

I checked and the payload "from" parameter exists.

How can I fix this?

Comment: i resorved....
SendEmailJob.post('https://api:key-###'\
'@api.mailgun.net/v3/###/messages', body: payload)

just add body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the body:

```
SendEmailJob.post('api:key-###'\ '@api.mailgun.net/v3/###/messages', body: payload)
```